# DLVO for complex solutions

Tags: electrostatics, interactions, nanoscience

I am working with a complex solution of 2 proteins and salt. I have been trying to use DLVO (Derjaguin, Landau, Vervey, and Overbeek) theory to get an approximation of the Van Der Waals attractive force ($F_{wppr}$) and the electric double layer repulsive force ($F_{el}$) between the molecules in the solution. However, textbooks only provide equations of Van der Waals and EDL forces for two types of molecules/spheres/cylinders. How can I calculate the forces for a more complex solution (2 proteins and 2 ions for example)?

$$
F_{wppr} = -\frac{A}{6 D^2}\left(\frac{r_1 r_2}{r_1 + r_2}\right)$$

$$F_{el} = \kappa Z \left(\frac{r_1 r_2}{r_1 + r_2} \right) e ^ {-\kappa D}$$

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: Proteins are very complex structures.  What you have to think in terms of, I suspect, is ["spherical cows"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cow), that is, some simplified model.